# How to crop specific part of an image in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, crop, firebase-mlkit

I'm going to use Firebase ML Vision to recognize some text in a given input image. My goal is to crop the area where the recognized text is located, I will show this cropped part as a preview in the app. Here is the steps I'm thinking of:

- Search the text and find its `boundingBox`,
- Crop image with the values of the `boundingBox`

So far I could only do the first part by grabbing the `boundingBox` from `TextBlock` lines, but I couldn't find a proper package/function to complete the second part.

How hard it can be?

Answer (score 0):

I am late but answering this for anyone else.
You can use flutter_native_image to crop an image using bounding box.

```
var signatureRect = Rect.fromLTRB(boundingBox!.left, boundingBox!.top,
          boundingBox!.right, boundingBox!.bottom);

final signatureImage = await FlutterNativeImage.cropImage(
 widget.cheque.path,
 signatureRect.left.toInt() - 180, // you can set these values according to your requirements
 signatureRect.top.toInt() - 220, // you can set these values according to your requirements
 signatureRect.width.toInt() + 400, // you can set these values according to your requirements
 signatureRect.height.toInt() + 170, // you can set these values according to your requirements
      );
```